# Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query

Tags: index, sql-server-2016, optimization, execution-plan, filtered-index

There is a similar question, but it is not the same:

[The query processor could not produce a query plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/78659/the-query-processor-could-not-produce-a-query-plan)

I have the following query, and the following filtered index, and I cannot see any reason why the query cannot use my filtered index described below:

-- the query - does not matter if I use the `max` or just the column, it does not like the index hint

```
SELECT -- MAX(AC1.changeDate)   
          AC1.changeDate
          FROM [dbo].[applicationStateChange]  AS ac1  WITH(INDEX(FI_ASC_ChangeDate))  
          WHERE ac1.applicationID = 130002
          AND AC1.newStatus = 'PLC'
```

-- and this is my filtered index - this index is just to optimise the query above

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FI_ASC_ChangeDate  
ON [dbo].[applicationStateChange] (   applicationID DESC)  
INCLUDE ( [changeDate] )
WHERE newStatus = 'PLC'  
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = On, 
DROP_EXISTING = ON, 
DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]
```

when I run the query, including the `index hint`, I get the following error message:

[image]

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 455 Query processor could not
>   produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query.
>   Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET
>   FORCEPLAN.

Have a missed something?

-- adding the column `newStatus` to the index did not solve the problem, neither in the index nor in the include:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FI_ASC_ChangeDate  
    ON [dbo].[applicationStateChange] (   applicationID DESC, newStatus ASC)  
    INCLUDE ( [changeDate] )
    WHERE newStatus = 'PLC'  
    WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = On, 
    DROP_EXISTING = ON, 
    DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
    ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FI_ASC_ChangeDate  
ON [dbo].[applicationStateChange] (   applicationID DESC)  
INCLUDE ( [changeDate],newStatus )
WHERE newStatus = 'PLC'  
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = On, 
DROP_EXISTING = ON, 
DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]
```

can it be the compatibility mode?

I noticed that if I remove the `filter` from the index, then the query accepts it fine. But that's not how I would like it.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX FI_ASC_ChangeDate  
ON [dbo].[applicationStateChange] (   applicationID DESC,newStatus
)  
INCLUDE ( [changeDate])
--WHERE newStatus = 'PLC'  
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = On, 
DROP_EXISTING = ON, 
DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]
```

[image]

Here is the definition of the table in question:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[applicationStateChange]') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[applicationStateChange] 
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[applicationStateChange] ( 
[applicationID]      INT                              NOT NULL,
[changeDate]         DATETIME                         NOT NULL,
[oldStatus]          CHAR(3)                              NULL,
[newStatus]          CHAR(3)                              NULL,
[oldStatusReasonID]  INT                                  NULL,
[newStatusReasonID]  INT                                  NULL,
[oldStatusReason]    VARCHAR(60)                          NULL,
[newStatusReason]    VARCHAR(60)                          NULL,
[oldOnHold]          BIT                                  NULL,
[newOnHold]          BIT                                  NULL,
CONSTRAINT   [PK_applicationStateChange]  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED    ([applicationID] asc, [changeDate] asc) WITH FILLFACTOR = 90,
CONSTRAINT   [FK_applicationStateChange_application]                             FOREIGN KEY ([applicationID]) REFERENCES [application]([applicationID]))

GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_applicationStateChange_ChangeDate] 
   ON [dbo].[applicationStateChange] ([changeDate] desc)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FI_ASC_ChangeDate] 
   ON [dbo].[applicationStateChange] ([applicationID] desc, [changeDate] asc, [newStatus] asc)
   WHERE ([newStatus]='PLC')
   WITH FILLFACTOR = 100
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

as I have seen on [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/129779/22336) when I add `option(recompile)` to my query it runs fine accepting the index hint:

```
SELECT   MAX(AC1.changeDate)   
         -- AC1.changeDate
          FROM [dbo].[applicationStateChange]  AS ac1  WITH(INDEX(FI_ASC_ChangeDate))  
          WHERE AC1.newStatus = 'PLC'  
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Still when I run the same query `without` the `option(recompile)` I get the same error

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 479 Query processor could not
>   produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query.
>   Resubmit the query without specifying any hints and without using SET
>   FORCEPLAN.

On my test environment however, I could afford running the following operation and after that no more problems with this filtered index:

```
ALTER DATABASE [JUNOCORE] SET PARAMETERIZATION SIMPLE;
```

to corroborate to my decision to do this in test I read the following articles:

[SQL Server Simple and Forced Parameterization](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2935/sql-server-simple-and-forced-parameterization/)

[Blitz Result: Forced Parameterization](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/forced-parameterization/)

Now I feel like changing my `[JUNOCORE] database` in LIVE also to [simple parameterization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/12/04/how-simple-parameterization-works/)

This then brings me to the following question:

[what elements of the workload or query plan cache I should have a look to decide Simple or Forced Parameterization in my databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222659/what-elements-of-the-workload-or-query-plan-cache-i-should-have-a-look-to-decide)